# Why the character head is down like neck is broken when using RayCast and LookAt?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script is attached to the ThirdPersonController and once i'm running the game the head is looking down like the neck is broken. Something scary.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveObjects : MonoBehaviour {

    bool isSpinning;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        isSpinning = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame

    void Update()
    {
        MovePlayerWithMouse();
    }

    private void MovePlayerWithMouse()
    {
        if (isSpinning == true)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider.name != "ThirdPersonController")
            {
                transform.LookAt(hit.point);
            }
            else
            {
                transform.LookAt(ray.GetPoint(100));  //the number here is compltely arbitrary
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot showing the player head when running the game:

[image: Head]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't have an IK pass on the model. LookAt() makes the transform rotate toward the point you want to look, and since it has not an IK , it just make that fun recoil.

Comment: I checked now in the Animator window i already have a new animation state i created before called it Walk. And on the left on the Base Layer i see that the IK is checked already. So what else should i do ? And how with the IK ?

Comment: Did you attach the IKControl script?
Have a look here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html

Comment: I found the problem. It was another script attached to the Main Camera the script name is: MouseOrbitImproved i think the back time i took from the wiki website. anyway removing this script or turning this script off solved the problem.